# Wordpress post showing 404 error in subfolder?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have installed wordpress in main domain (fewinfo.com) and its running successfully. now, i have installed wordpress in subfolder (fewinfo.com/wp) but when i check post inner page it shows 404 error.

I have updated .htaccess using below code but not working and also I have tried without "wp" that also not working.

NOTE : Website have hosted in Godaddy

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: temp remove htaccess and try to run admin panel first.

Comment: do you mean wordpress admin? if it's working fine, my problem only my post is showing 404 error.

Comment: i have check your site working fine here : fewinfo.com/wp

Comment: issue on single page spacing issue in header & footer (remove this one first)

Comment: 404 page in called parent site content. Please check this one why issue created

Comment: they are both using the same database? if so, it won't work. Try with a new database for the /wp instance

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings » Permalinks, and simply click on Save Changes button.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace or export data using [Wp Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/).
Easy to replace any url in your current database without lose any data or serialization issue.

[Changing the Site URL multiple ways.](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/wordpress-changing-the-site-url-and-home-settings)

After Change Url Update:

Go to

> Settings » Permalinks

Update permalink.

Comment: I donot want merge both website because both are different and also tried with update permalinks. but not working.